# angular-formly triggering remote errors

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

How can I trigger error on filed ? Assume we got form consist of name, email, password. We check email uniqness on server side, and server sends object like { email: ['already taken', 'another error' ] etc. How can i tap into the form and trigger those on fields?

Comment: Do you have any code you can show us of your previous attempts?

Comment: I recommend you give this free egghead.io lesson a look: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-angular-formly-custom-validation?pl=advanced-angular-forms-with-angular-formly

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you want to do a async validation of an input field. I assume you wanna make something like [this](http://embed.plnkr.co/s4jJAOqehBkFUC9osMsy/preview).

For the concrete solution see this [Blog](http://www.codelord.net/2014/11/02/angularjs-1-dot-3-taste-async-validators/)

Comment: @Elrond is using angular-formly which has a simple `validators` API which uses the `$asyncValidators` API under the hood. This answer is great for normal angular forms, and could actually work with angular-formly, but there's a simpler way.

Comment: Not exacly, async validator is ok - it will valid "on fly" but by the time user hit "submit" many things can happen. Final validation is on server side and it returns object with errors if needed. I can get this response and display it in a alert box or somthing, but it would be great to applay some error style to the fields with errors etc. In essens i need some tap function to do makeInvalid(fieldKey) etc... is there smth in angular-formly ?

Answer (score 0):

I see - wasn't aware angular-formly..

you can call your validaton service in thre formly asyncValidator and then parse the result and manually set the validation state on the field using `scope.fc.$setValidity`. The messages can be registered in the `validation` section.

```
    validators: {
      asyncMultiValidator: {
        expression: function(viewValue, modelValue, scope) {
          $http.get('...validation-url...').success(function(result) {
            //assuming the service returns a map of validation results as {'validationName': isValid (boolean) }
            angular.foreach(result, function(isValid, validationName) {
              scope.fc.$setValidity(validationName, isValid);
            });
          })

          // this dummy validator is always valid
          return true;
        },
        message: 'dummy message - not being used'
      }
    },
    validation: {
      messages: {
        required: function(viewValue, modelValue, scope) {
          return scope.to.label + ' is required'
        },
        remote: function(viewValue, modelValue, scope) {
          return 'some remote error';
        }
      }
```

Comment: If the form passes all local and remote validation on client side then it's valid

Comment: And how about this scenario: form passes all validation on client side and is submitted to the backend - here backend tries to save, but validation fails and it returns object { 'email': ['email already taken'] } - from this point i would like to pass this to formly-form to trigger this error. I DON'T wont to validate this async (on the fly) but after submit.

Comment: I tried to run signup.form.$setValidity('email',false); and this makes submit button disabled again, but the email field does not change to error state, also makeing submit enabled again is not possible

Comment: you have to set the validation on the FIELD level. currently you just set the validation of the whole form. try: `signup.form.email.$setValidity` - don't know if that is the right syntax, but you need to use the field instead of the form

Comment: ok, but how to iterate over fields? - they are not in collection within formly-form ex: formly_1_input_displayName_0: Object formly_1_input_email_1: Objectformly_1_input_password_2: Object and so on ....

Comment: why do you won't to iterate over the fields? you can access them directly by using their name (define `name` in the fields configuration if you don't wanna deal with generic field names). - you can iterate over all properties of the form, just filter skip the fields which start with a `$`

Comment: about validation messages: i got validation: {
        show: true,
        messages: {
          required: function() { return 'ok'; },
          email: function() { return 'not ok'; }
        }
      }, under email field. Css error style is displayed  but there is no error message?